# How do I disable "An update for GNOME Shell extensions" notifications?

Tags: updates, gnome-shell-extension

Or automatize the updates? Or delete/disable the update notifier? It is not in the list of "installed extensions" and re-installing it does not help.

Where are its files located?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

To get rid of the update notification, you will need to disabling the automatic check for updates to Gnome Shell Extensions in preferences of the "Gnome Shell Preferences" extension of your browser.
In Firefox:
- Select Tools - Add-ons (or "Add-ons" under the Open Menu button)
- Select "extensions" in the menu on the left, then click the "Preferences" button next to "GNOME Shell Integration".
- Scroll to the bottom of the page, where you can disable the option "Check for extensions update".

The automatic check does do only that: check whether there is an update and notify you. If yo do not want the notification, then it does not make sense to check. So deleting the notification means you need to disable the check.

There is currently no mechanism where updates to Gnome Shell extensions that have been installed by the user are automatically installed. In contrast, extensions that have been installed system-wide will be automatically updated like any other software through your package manager.

Comment: How can I install extensions (like Caffeine, Open Weather, Audio switcher, Places indicator, Window list) "system-wide"?

Comment: For Chrome users, this setting can be found under More Tools -> Extensions -> GNOME Shell integration -> Options

Comment: Thanks this is great to know how to disable them. Once I arrived on the settings page I instead chose to just check once a weekish, and set it to around 200 hours. The default of 6 hours is unnecessary and I think it should be changed to at least 24 hours.

Answer (score -2):

**Files are located at:** ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions

**disable notifications for app:**
settings->notifications
select that app and turn notifications off

Comment: I don't believe that answers question. You don't want to disable every notification from gnome shell itself, you just want to disable extension updater from needlessly annoying you

Comment: isnt "gnome shell integration" what fires the notifications?