# Why do some shell extensions always report they need an update even if they don't?

Tags: gnome-shell-extension, 21.04

I see some strange behaviour here. I'm running Ubuntu 21.04 and Gnome-shell on a number of computers, and it works very well indeed. BUT there seems to be a small glitch with a couple of the extensions, namely `Autohide Battery` and `Impatience`. When I go to `extensions.gnome.org` and select `Installed Extensions`, these two extensions always display a green Update button, even shortly after they have have been updated. This is just a tiny irritation and nothing more, but do someone know about a solution? These extensions have different authors; I have contacted one of them on the extensions web site, but received no answer.

Edit: I have removed all system extensions, so `/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/` is empty.

My local extensions are these:

```
$ ls -la ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/
total 68
drwxrwxr-x 17 bernt bernt 4096 Jul 19 23:49 .
drwx------  4 bernt bernt 4096 Jul 21 20:19 ..
drwxrwxr-x  2 bernt bernt 4096 Jun 22 16:03 all-windows@ezix.org
drwxrwxr-x  6 bernt bernt 4096 Jul 14 23:10 arcmenu@arcmenu.com
drwxrwxr-x  4 bernt bernt 4096 Jun 22 16:01 autohide-battery@sitnik.ru
drwxrwxr-x  4 bernt bernt 4096 Mar 21 16:10 auto-move-windows@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
drwxrwxr-x  5 bernt bernt 4096 Mar 16 00:52 caffeine@patapon.info
drwxrwxr-x  4 bernt bernt 4096 Jul 19 23:49 ding@rastersoft.com
drwxrwxr-x  4 bernt bernt 4096 Mar 16 01:23 extensions@abteil.org
drwxrwxr-x  3 bernt bernt 4096 Jul  1 16:19 impatience@gfxmonk.net
drwxrwxr-x  5 bernt bernt 4096 Jun 22 16:01 lockkeys@vaina.lt
drwxrwxr-x  3 bernt bernt 4096 Mar 21 16:10 places-menu@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
drwxrwxr-x  4 bernt bernt 4096 Jun  3 23:45 putWindow@clemens.lab21.org
drwxrwxr-x  2 bernt bernt 4096 May 25 23:59 removeaccesibility@lomegor
drwxrwxr-x  2 bernt bernt 4096 Jun 11 01:17 user-id-in-top-panel@fthx
drwxrwxr-x  3 bernt bernt 4096 Apr  3 10:27 user-theme@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
drwxrwxr-x  4 bernt bernt 4096 Apr  3 10:27 window-list@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
```

Comment: A workaround is to disable automatic updates of extensions: https://askubuntu.com/questions/914532/how-do-i-disable-an-update-for-gnome-shell-extensions-notifications

Comment: @vanadium - thanks, but I don't receive update notifications from the two I mentioned. Only when I check manually, the green "update" button lights up. As I said, a minor nuisance only.

Comment: Minor indeed, but you better edit your question to clarify the context where you see this, i.e., in the Gnome Shell Extensions website, I guess.

Comment: Restart gnome-shell, or log out/in, and recheck https://extensions.gnome.org/local/

Comment: @vanadium Why would you want/recommend to disable auto updates of extensions?

Comment: @heynnema Unfortunately, no. Restart or logout has been tried a few times, and these extensions still sport the update button.

Comment: @BerntRibbum Edit your question and show me `ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions` and `ls -al /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions`. Tell me which extensions have the update icon.

Comment: @heynnema There is no need for that. I have no "system" extensions left; being the sole user of these machines I keep everything local. Whenever any extension except the two listed above needs an update, I get a message and react to it. No messages from the two at all. Normally there are no extensions with the udate icon except the two.

Comment: @BerntRibbum Well, if you don't wish to give me the requested information, I can't help you.

Comment: @heynnema Updated. Only the two mentioned have the update icon.

Comment: @BerntRibbum I see that you've made comments on those two extensions web pages. Try this. At https://extensions.gnome.org/local/, turn off ALL extensions, restart gnome-shell or log out/in, then try to update those TWO extensions, restart gnome-shell, re-enable those TWO extensions, and recheck the status.

Comment: @BerntRibbum If the above comment doesn't allow the updates, uninstall those two extensions with the X button, then reinstall them, and you should have the latest versions.

Comment: @heynnema I suspected it would lead nowhere, but tried all of your suggestions. No change. Bummer! Thanks for your patience in any case: much appreciated.

Comment: @BerntRibbum Uninstall and reinstall didn't fix it either? Bum extensions then.

Comment: @heynnema I had reinstalled them a number of times already, but without the extra steps you suggested. A shame, but this is the reality when all one pays is one's own time. We have certainly spent some time today both of us!