# Gnome shell extension update: ERROR

Tags: gnome, updates, xorg, gnome-shell-extension

Ubuntu 21.04, Xorg, gnome-shell 3.28.4.

I occasionally get a message that this-or-that Gnome shell extension should be updated. (Latest: Lock Keys).
Trying to update the extension invariably leads to the ubiquitous red "ERROR" message on the extension list (and a defunct extension). The solution is always to restart X (Alt+F2, r), then everything works again (until the next update is signalled).
When booting, I always choose GNOME on Xorg, as that gives me the desktop I want.

But this extension update behaviour? Why do I get this, the system is apparently unfinished. Anyone? Thanks :)

Comment: Exactly same config as me. And I experience the same things. And as you already mentioned, the solution is to restart GNOME. This is probably a bug, so I do not care much, as long as everything is as expected after the restart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, installing Gnome Shell extensions from the Gnome Extensions website is not by default supported in an Ubuntu install. So you enable and do this on your *own* responsability. This is not a matter of "the system apparently being unfinished.".

Many Gnome Extensions are made by volunteers like you and me (or rather, those who know java scripting anyway -;). The interface against which developers make extensions is 1) poorly documented and 2) still changes between versions. Accordingly, a newer version working on a newer version of Gnome Shell may not work anymore on an older version.

Your best bet probably is to [disable automatic updates](https://askubuntu.com/questions/914532/how-do-i-disable-an-update-for-gnome-shell-extensions-notifications) of extensions. If an extension breaks, remove it and try reinstalling it, however specifically selecting a "Shell version" from the drop down menu.

The most reliable experience with Gnome Shell extensions is to install them preferably from the Ubuntu software sources, i.e., using Ubuntu Software or through the command line (type `sudo apt install gnome-shell-extension` then <kbd>Tab</kbd> to autocomplete to see all available packages). These versions were specifically tested for your current Ubuntu version.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu 21.04 is an interim release and this issue would probably benefit from being reported as a bug [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug/?no-redirect) so developers can be aware of it before release of the next LTS expected April 2022.

> Interim releases will introduce new capabilities from Canonical and
> upstream open source projects, they serve as a proving ground for
> these new capabilities. Many developers run interim releases because
> they provide newer compilers or access to newer kernels and newer
> libraries, and they are often used inside rapid devops processes like
> CI/CD pipelines where the lifespan of an artefact is likely to be less
> than the support period of the interim release. Interim releases
> receive full security maintenance for ‘main’ during their lifespan.

[this reference](https://ubuntu.com/about/release-cycle) explains more.

Comment: Your answer is not directly related to the question.